# ManagementObject возвращает исключение NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, wmi

Пробую получить значение установленного антивируса на компьютере

```
const string SECURITY = @"root\SecurityCenter2";
using var Anti = new ManagementObjectSearcher(SECURITY, "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct");
using var itemsAnti = Anti.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(itemsAnti["displayName"]?.ToString());
```

Но получаю ошибку: `Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.`в `itemsAnti["displayName"]?.ToString()`

Попробовал сделать проверку:

```
if (itemsAnti.Properties.Count != 0)
```

или

```
if (itemsAnti["displayName"] != null)
```

Всё ровно возвращает исключение `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 4):

Очевидно, что `null` является `itemsAnti`, т. к. вы получаете его из `FirstOrDefault`, а т. к. `default(<any class name>) == null`, то и выбрасывается `NullReferenceException`. Вы получаете исходную последовательность из seacher'а, для которой свойственно мочь быть пустой; и вы из этой пустой последовательности пытаетесь получить первый элемент, если он не найден, то `null`, что вы и получили (это значит, что последовательность пуста).

Если бы вы использовали .NET Core с `Project/PropertyGroup/Nullable` равным `enable` (`.csproj`), то вы бы получили предупреждение от компилятора, что возвращаемый объект потенциально может быть `null` ([ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)).

Comment: Заменил на: `var itemsAnti = Anti.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().Select(x => (string)x.GetPropertyValue("displayName")).FirstOrDefault();` Так не получаю исключения.

Comment: @r3xq1 исключения и не будет выдаваться, т. к. оно выдаётся не при получении `null`, а при его использовании. проверьте `Count()` этой последовательности

Comment: @r3xq1 проявите уважение, я вам помочь хочу, а вы не отвечаете(